# How to enable PCNTL on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: php-7, ubuntu-server

I'm wondering how to enable pcntl extension in PHP7 running on Ubuntu server 16.04.
I saw this http://www.crimulus.com/2010/07/30/howto-enable-pcntl-in-ubuntu-php-installations/ but do we really have to recompile PHP7?

It surprises me as other extensions are usually simple to add with apt-get.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

for ubuntu 18 and 20:

1. `php -v`
   result for example: `PHP 7.4.10`
2. `sudo wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.10.tar.gz`
   replace 7.4.10 with your php version.
3. `sudo tar xfz php-7.4.10.tar.gz && sudo rm -rf php-7.4.10.tar.gz`
   replace 7.4.10 with your php version.
4. `cd php-7.4.10/ext/pcntl/`
   replace 7.4.10 with your php version.
5. `sudo phpize`
   if phpize is not installed you can install it with `apt install php7.0-dev`
6. `sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config`
7. `sudo make && sudo make install`
   the result must be like `Installing shared extensions: /usr/lib/php/20190902/`
8. `cd ../../../ && sudo rm -rf php-7.4.10`
   replace 7.4.10 with your php version.
9. `cd /etc/php/7.4`
   replace 7.4 with your php version.
10. `sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=pcntl.so' > ./mods-available/pcntl.ini"`
11. `sudo nano ./cli/php.ini` then add `extension=pcntl`.
    repeat this job for `sudo nano ./apache2/php.ini` or `sudo nano ./fpm/php.ini`.
12. in all above `php.ini` there is `disable_functions` that include `pcntl` prefix. you must enable which one you want.
13. restart your apache2 or fpm with:
    `sudo service apache2 restart`
    `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`
    replace 7.4 with your php version.
14. you can check it with `die(extension_loaded('pcntl'));` in test.php

note: if you got error : `PHP Warning: Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`, remove `extension=pcntl` only in `cli/php.ini`

Comment: Works fine for Ubuntu Server 20 and PHP 8.0.8. Some remarks:
a part of step 11 can be skipped (e.g. adding `extension=pcntl.so` to php.ini), since we already added that in step 10, but don't forget to call `sudo phpenmod pcntl` on Ubuntu instead.
step 14: you can also check your `phpinfo()` output

Comment: Step 7: sudo make && sudo make install throw this error:  `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   53 |  if (zend_sigaction(signo, &act, &oact) < 0) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:210: php_signal.lo] Error 1`

I am using php7.4.33 version.

Comment: after 1 hour, i found this! thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

You don't need apt-get install anything else.

pcntl module was included when you installed php by package manager, try to `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it may be helpful.
You can also use this to confirm if you have or don't have it.

```
php -i | grep pcntl
//pcntl suppport=>enable
```

Also list all my installed module by package manager.

```
sudo apt install php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-imap php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml
```

Comment: that actually works only for the CLI. It might be disabled in the web handler

Answer (score 1):

According to your needs, the solution for me was to use the following tutorial from [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com).

Today, current release is `7.4.11`, but you can change it.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.11.tar.gz
tar xfz php-7.4.11.tar.gz
cd php-7.4.11
```

On the next you will find `--enable-pcntl` what is the interesting thing.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-7.4 --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-zlib --enable-gd --with-pgsql --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --with-zip --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-jpeg --with-openssl --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-ftp --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-intl --with-pear --enable-fpm
```

Please follow the entire tutorial for a complete working solution here :
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-compile-and-install-php-7.4-on-ubuntu-18-04/